# Child div wider than parent but behind parent. Is there a way to do this?

Tags: css, layout, positioning

Below is the CSS I'm using to try and position the #lower-content-sub div to stick to the bottom of my #content div. I'm trying to position it like the home page at [Home page](http://boyd.lottmandesign.com)!. I'm just not that savvy at positioning and could use a little help. I'd like it to stick to the bottom so when the content div moves, the lower content will stay with it.

Is there a way for a child div to extend wider than the parent but also sit behind the parent?

The page where you can see the issue is [here](http://boyd.lottmandesign.com/about/boyd.html).

Below is the CSS:

```
#content {
width:990px;
height:auto;
min-height:540px;
background-color:#fff;
margin: -151px auto 0 auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.62);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.62);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 30px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.62);
}

#lower-content-sub {
height:250px;
width:100%;
background-color:#fff;
border-top: 5px solid #666;
border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
background-image:url(../images/noise.jpg);
}
```

And the HTML

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="lower-content-sub">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try applying this properties.

To the `#content` div set a `position:relative;`

To the `#lower-content-sub` set a `position:absolute; bottom:0;` and a `margin-top:250px;` (margin-top equals lower-content-sub height)

Hope it guides you to the solution.

Comment: Yes, that helped. Now I just have to figure out how to get the #lower-content-sub behind the content. The positioning of it worked! thank you :)

Comment: Try applying the z-index property to both divs. to the `#content{z-index:99}` and the lower one a `z-index:9`. It may be not necessary to apply this property to both divs.

Comment: Ok, wow. Works well now. Is there a reason the footer sticks to the #content div now? Even though, order wise, it should be below the #lower-content div?

Comment: Well, to fix the issue I just had to create a new div for the sub page footer. I couldn't find out why the footer was sticking to the bottom of the content div...